# Bootstrap - Using a carousel as a fixed background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to create a responsive site with the help of Bootsrap but faced some problem (due to the lack of experience).

The main idea is to create a simple Bootstrap corousel which should be a fixed or slightly moving backgroung (example - https://modernthemes.net/demo/?theme=proper), so that after rolling the page down the rest of the content will overflow this background.

What I have now is - HTML:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(static/header/1st.jpg);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(static/header/2nd.jpg);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(static/header/3rd.jpg);"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

But I do not know where should I use the

```
no-repeat center center fixed;
```

or something else to get the similar (like https://modernthemes.net/demo/?theme=proper) result.

I have already found some similar topics but none of them worked properly in my case. That is why I would be very thankful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the example that you show ( https://modernthemes.net/demo/?theme=prope), the background have a position fixed, and with the scroll the image goes up like the rest of the slide but the background position off the image change to look like it's fixed.

Comment: Um.. Yeah, that's what I have already mentioned in my post) I just need to figure out how to make this fixed background using Bootstrap carousel.